# Xcode is requesting a profile for app extension which is a liveActivity

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, provisioning-profile

each time I try to do a release Xcode asks me to select a provisioning profile for the live Activity app extension and im unable to generate one because the Bundle id is not in the app developer account i cant find it even though it should be signed with the app itself

side note the app uses eSim provisioning profile its an eSim app

[image]